# xdmp:document-insert() document distribution across forests

Tags: marklogic

What algorithm is used to select forest for xdmp:document-insert() and what factors influence distribution of documents across forests?

I am seeing xdmp:document-insert is not distributing documents equally. I tried passing output of cts:uris to xdmp:document-assign and then populated a map with key=forest-name and value=uris count.

let $index := xdmp:document-assign($uri,$forests-count) 
  let $forest-name := xdmp:forest-name($forests[$index])

When $forests-count is low ,the documents are moreover balanced across forests but if no. of forests is high(~ 50) it is making uri distribution uneven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm uses a 64-bit hash, so it has plenty of address space for 50+ forests. There are deployed clusters with hundreds of forests, perhaps thousands. With the clusters I work with, document counts are typically within 10% of the mean. That is uniform enough, because most forest operations are `O(log n)`.

Placement tends to work best when the URIs themselves are uniformly distributed. URIs that are sequential numbers, for example, may clump together more.